# Alinear icono y texto

Tags: html, css

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de querer poner un icono y texto en la misma linea.
La idea es que quede como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema es que me aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle;">
                <div style="float:left;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:dodgerblue; font-size:25px;"></span></div>
                <div style="margin-top:15px;">Todas las manzanas han sido asignadas a un supervisor</div>
            </div>
```

Alguien que pueda ayudarme por favor...

Comment: Ayudarías su pusieras el código de la clase enlacesfavoritos, que es la que afecta al texto.

Comment: perdón, esa clase ya no la uso porque tampoco me funciono, se me olvido quitarla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te aconsejo que le eches un ojo a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). He alineado de forma horizontal el contenido de las etiquetas hijas (con `display: flex`) y añadido un pequeño margen al texto (con `margin-left: 10px`).

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <div style="display: flex">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle" style="color: blue;"></i>
        <div style="margin-left: 10px">Todas las manzanas han sido asignadas a un supervisor</div>
    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono muy bien

Comment: @fmye tu error no es flexbox, tu error lo tenías al aplicar un `margin-top` al texto, por obvias razones esto hace que tu ícono se vea en una posición distinta relativa a lo demás.

Answer (score 7):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dotted 1px red;
  padding: 5px
}

.demo-text{
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:25px;
}

span.glyphicon
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:dodgerblue; font-size:25px;">
                </span>
                <span class="demo-text">Todas las manzanas han sido asignadas a un supervisor</span>
            </div>
```

Espero te sirva!

> Créditos:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802067/align-bootstrap-glyphicons-vertically-with-text-on-both-sides

Comment: Esta es la forma correcta de implementarlo debido a que el OP está asignando un tamaño de fuente al ícono, el comportamiento se corrige al dar el mismo valor al alto de la línea.

Comment: Por favor, agrega una pequeña explicación de lo que has hecho en el código para ayudar mucho mejor al OP.

Answer (score 4):

Lo mejor es que use [flexbox](https://flaviocopes.com/flexbox/). Te paso un ejemplo utilizándolo. Además he añadido un pequeño `margin`abajo y a la izquierda para ajustar mejor el texto con lo que quieres.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.customSpan {
  margin:0 0 4px 4px;  
}
.customIcon {
  color:dodgerblue;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign customIcon"></span></div>
    <div class="customSpan">Todas las manzanas han sido asignadas a un supervisor</div>
</div>
```

PD: Acostúmbrate a utilizar clases CSS para tener todo bien ordenado y no tirar tanto de estilos inline (`style`)

Comment: Muchas gracias tu ejemplo me fue de mucha ayuda